# Why does a char with 2 spaces print a int value?

Tags: c++, char

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        //print a char including two spaces
       cout<<'  '<<endl;
        //output shows me 8224 
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

[Here is the screenshot of the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jLn7M.png)

**Why does it show me 8224?**

Comment: That won't compile, much less run and print anything.

Comment: `char * p` is not a character. It is a pointer to a character

Comment: The value of a multi-character character literal is implementation-dependent. Don't use them without consulting the documentation for your compiler.

Comment: Why output shows me integer value when i print a char including two spaces?

Comment: your code **does not compile** https://godbolt.org/z/oc4n8Mv3G

Comment: You're not printing a `char`, you're printing first a `char*`, and then a `char**` reinterpreted as a `void*`. If you manage to compile it (no compiler will accept it unless you explicitly disable the initial, useful, type error) the first has undefined behaviour, and the second is the location of `p`, not its value.

Answer (score 0):

You're printing a pointer, not the character. `char *p` is a pointer to a character, and when you print pointers, they look like integers.

The problem is not `'  '`, although that is a problem, because single quotes expect only one character. Double quotes are used for string literals, which can be stored in a `char *` pointer.